# capturing exit codes properly and exit script at point of failure

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have below block of code in `bash`. I am trying to `exit` the script whenever there is a failure but unable to do so.

```
#!/bin/bash

jarFilePath=/usr/jars
username=test_user
password=password
host=10.10.10.10

val_query="SELECT * FROM test_db.test_table"

echo "${val_query}"

content=$(java -jar ${jarFilePath} -u ${username},${password} -n ${host} -c "${val_query}") 

if ! $content; then
   echo "Problem in executing query"
   exit 201
fi

touch /home/$username/script_passed.txt
```

When I pass wrong credentials the script will fail. The error is below

```
SQLException: [10]: authentication failed
```

Which is expected but the script doesn't terminate at this error message. It is executing the `touch` command

What am I doing wrong here and how can I exit the script at point of failure

Comment: Add a line `set -e` to the top of your script.

Comment: @Roadowl  I added `set -e`  as suggested but the issue still persists

Comment: With `set -x` or `echo "content=${content}"` you will see, that `$content` is not a program to execute, Does your `java` program exit with an errorcode when it fails (test it with `$?`), or do you need to redirect stderr to stdout before looking for an SQLException in the `content`?

Comment: Did you mean `if test -z "$content"; then ...`  The line `if ! $content` is extremely smelly.

Comment: Error messages belong on stderr: `echo "Problem in executing query" >&2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the java command has a non-zero exit status, so you would do:

```sh
content=$(java -jar ${jarFilePath} -u ${username},${password} -n ${host} -c "${val_query}") 
rc=$?

if ((rc != 0)); then
   echo "Problem in executing query"
   exit 201
elif [[ -z $content ]]; then
   echo "Empty results"
fi
```

Note that the `content` variable holds the **output** of the command, not the **exit status**.

`if ! $content; then ...` will execute the value of the content variable *as a command*, and you'll get the "true" branch if that execution has a  non-zero exit status (from the `!`).

Comment: I am facing error while using the above code in your answer. everything is working fine when `val_query` has everything correct. `val_query` here is nothing but a `sql` query. Now if there are any syntax errors in the `val_query` then the output of `echo $rc is 0` which is wrong it should be a non zero value. Could you please let me know how can I fix it

Comment: That fix is on the Java side.